# Is AuthenticateUserQuery a valid Query in CQRS

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs, mediatr

Recently I have been trying to implement CQRS + DDD in my new ASP.NET Core project, as CQRS and DDD are very new to me, I read a lot of articles and examples online but could not get a deeper understanding.

***Generic example:***

I have the following:

**Structure:**

`Front-End` <==> `Controller` <==> `Mediatr` <==> `Command Handler` <==> `Repository`

Or

`Front-End` <==> `Controller` <==> `Mediatr` <==> `Query Handler` <==> `Reader`

I use `Mediatr` library to handle all my commands and queries.

`Repository` returns/save `Aggregate Root/Domain/WriteModel`, `Reader` returns `ReadModel`.

**Aggregate Root/Domain/WriteModel:**
`class User { string UserId , string Password }`

**Command:**
`CreateUserCommand` which takes in new user's `UserId` and `Password` and create a new `User`, then save it with `Repository`. Publish a `UserCreatedEvent`.

Now I want to create a function for clients to authenticate with `UserId` and `Password`. The function should have `UserId` and `Password` as input, and I will return `UserAuthResult` which has a `bool` field, true if `UserId` and `Password` is valid

I am thinking to create a `AuthenticateUserQuery` but I am not sure if it is actually a valid `Query`, or just a `Domain Service`.

The code flow of `AuthenticateUserQuery` would probably be:

1. `Controller` send `AuthenticateUserQuery` to `Mediatr`
2. `Mediatr` execute `AuthenticateUserQueryHandler.Handle()`
3. `AuthenticateUserQueryHandler` get `UserAuthDetailReadModel` from `UserAuthDetailReader`
4. Do authenticate with query's `UserId` + `Password` and `UserAuthDetailReadModel`
5. Return `UserAuthResult`

**Questions Time!**

1. From the description above, `AuthenticateUserQuery` only performs query/read, is it a valid `Query` or `Domain Service`
2. If Question #1 is `Query`, is `UserAuthResult` a `ReadModel`? (Since it is returned from a `Query`)
3. If Question #2 is a YES, is `UserAuthDetailReadModel` also a `ReadModel`? (Since it is NOT returned from `Query`, but return from `Reader`)
4. If Question #1 is `Query`, does it mean as long as the `Query` only performs query/read with `ReadModel`, the name of `Query` does not limit to `CRUD` style of prefix (e.g. `GetUserAuthDetailQuery`)?
5. If Question #1 is `Domain Service`, would you please give me some idea on how to implement it? (e.g. Class + Method signature)
6. If Question #1 is neither, would you please give me some insight?

Appreciate any related suggestions and ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authenticating a user has the nature of a command, not a query (you may not update any DB, but still you are asking to make some operation, authentication, on a user, not to query data for a user).

Retrieving data (UserAuthDetailReadModel) as part of a use-case, as well as returning a success indication, does not make this use-case query.

Having that said, you can infer that we are dealing here neither with a query nor with a domain service, but with a command: AuthenticateUserCommand.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit on why authenticating a user has the nature of a command?

Comment: When you authenticate a user you perform necessary actions that let the user enter your system, meaning that authentication has side effect that changes system state, and this is the definition of a command. Also, your main purpose here is not to return data (I am not considering the return of a success indication to be data, its just an indication for whether or not changing system state succeeded).

Comment: Does the `AuthenticateUser` thing have side effects, does it update the system state? To me it does. After the execution, the system will either have +1 authenticated user OR have +1 authentication failure, and both those data points are important in any application I've seen so far. So I think it is a command. After the command is finished you will need to query your read model to get the results if you want to follow CQRS.

Comment: I think I understand what you are suggesting. However, the more I think about it, the more I think this problem does not exist from the beginning. I am proposing the following: I have `CreateUserCommand` and `GetUserAuthDetailQuery`, in which `UserAuthDetail` is a read model of `User`'s auth related data. Assuming I have an endpoint `POST /user/token` for getting a token, it is the responsibility of the Controller (ASP.NET) to use 'GetUserAuthDetailQuery' to get `UserAuthDetail` and check if the POST request is valid, and issue a token to the requester. It is not CQRS's job to create a token.

Comment: Of course, the Controller should call e.g. `UserAuthenticateService` to check the request, and `UserAuthenticateService` use 'GetUserAuthDetailQuery' to get `UserAuthDetail` for checking. For the sake of SOLID!

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to make things more complicated than they have to be.

CQRS takes its vocabulary from [Bertrand Meyer's concept of Command Query Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction) (CQS). The distinction really isn't difficult.

- A Command is an operation that has a side effect, but returns no data.
- A Query is an operation that returns data, but has no side effect.

CQRS elaborates on that idea to define an architectural style, but the definitions remain.

CQS imposes the rule that any operation must be *either* a Command *or* a Query; it can't be both in that terminology. This notion also carries over to CQRS.

In mainstream statically typed languages like C# and Java, Commands are easy to recognise. Since a Command is forbidden from returning data, it *must* have the return type `void`.

By elimination, then, if you follow CQS, methods that have return types must be Queries.

Since your authentication operation returns a result then it *can't* be a Command.

Technically, languages like C# or Java don't enforce CQS, but if you can convince yourself that the authentication operation has no side effect (which I wouldn't expect it to have), then it must be a Query.

Comment: Interesting! So CQRS is not as strict as I read from a lot of source from online. You answer enhance my confidence of implementing the function as Query. However, I am moving toward to another direction which, instead of implementing 'AuthenticateUserQuery', I should implement 'GetUserTokenQuery' and move authenticate logic on or before Controller layer. It is quite meaningless to call 'AuthenticateUserQuery' as eventually what the client wants is a token for future requests. This design should help as I will not be implementing Event Sourcing so the Query-side should be more straight-foward.